# ASP.NET MVC registration forms based on Dropdownlist Selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario whereby `DropDownList` selection will show the appropriate registration form for the selection. For example, the `DropDownList` consists of 2 types of users:

- Student
- Admin

If I select the Student user type from the `DropDownList`, the view will show the Student registration `form` and the same goes to Lecturer whereby the `view` will show the Lecturer registration `form` and hide the Student `form`.

The following is the code that I written for this:
`View`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <h4>Create a new user account.</h4>
    <hr />


    <!--Select the Role Type for the User-->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleList, new SelectList(Model.RoleList, "Value", "Text"), "-- Select user type --", new { @id = "Role", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Admin Section -->
    <div class="AdminSection">
        <form id="AdminForm">
            <h5>Admin</h5>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtEmail" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPassword" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtConfirmPassword" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" id="Adminbutton" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Student Section -->
    <div class="StudentForm" style="display:none;">
        <form id="StudentForm">
            <h5>Student</h5>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StudentId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StudentId, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
      </form>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
       </div>
   </div>
```

`Script:`

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".StudentSection").hide();
    $(".AdminSection").hide();

    $("#Role").change(function () {
        if ($("#Role").val() == "Student") {
            $(".StudentSection").show();
            $(".AdminSection").hide();
        }
        else if ($("#Role").val() == "Admin") {
            $(".AdminSection").show();
            $(".StudentSection").hide();            
        }
        else {
            $(".AdminSection").hide();
            $(".StudentSection").hide();
        }
    });
```

The above code does work and show the appropriate `form`, however when I click the Submit button, it does not get the appropriate data from the chosen registration `form`. What is the problem here?

Comment: Show your rendered html of dropdown ?

Comment: You have nested forms there - is that what you intended?

Comment: @Monza i'm not really sure how nested form works though..but I don't really know how to show different form within a view

Comment: I'd propose that you have one form but show/hide divs containing elements for the form section you didn't want to have visible.
This is the type of problem that binding libraries like Knockout are designed to solve but that's another story (there's a learning curve ;)

Comment: [Nested forms are invalid](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element), per the HTML spec. I would start by fixing that.

Comment: I think you should get rid of outer form, and submit button. Use "DropDownList" instead of "DropDownListFor". And inside both the forms use @Html.HiddenFor to bind your field with the model. Update those hidden field using javascript and I think that should update your model when you submit the form.